# Django: Dependent Dropdown List

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I want to implement Dependent Dropdown List in my project.
Here are the models:

```
class ObjectName(models.Model):
    objectName=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    objFullForm=models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.objectName

class ActionObject(models.Model):
    objectName=models.ForeignKey(ObjectName,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    action=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.action
```

When the user selects an object in the **ActionObject** template, the Action should automatically list the related fields.
I tried using Django-smartselects but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow this tutorial which explains everything you need step by step to implement a dependent dropdown list:

[How to Implement Dependent/Chained Dropdown List with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)

Comment: it only loads when the submit button is clicked

Comment: I assume that you have followed the tutorial. When you write it only loads when the submit button is clicked, then the implementation of the code seems not to be OK. Have you checked the AJAX site what the output is?

Comment: If the link helped to solve your problem, it would be nice if you mark the question a solved.